# C# Lucene.net でデータの有無を判定するには

Tags: c#, lucene

以下の環境でアプリを開発しています。

- Visual Studio 2019
- C#
- Windows 10
- Lucene.net

Lucene.net で単語の有り無しを判定したいのですが、現在はタイトルフィールドで単語 "foo" を検索する場合、「title:foo」としています。

そこで、タイトルフィールドに「title:単語なし（空白）」「title:単語あり（空白ではない）」を検索する場合、どのようなクエリ構文にすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。

Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("title", "*"));

これで「title:単語あり（空白ではない）」が検索できることが、わかりました。

どうもお騒がせしました。